# Fujitsu Lifebook Forgot Password

Tags: password-recovery

I just discovered my old Fujitsu lifebook that's about 13 years old. (P-Series) I also discovered that I totally forgot my old password. I have no revery disc.

I tried <kbd>F12</kbd>, and <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and looked at all of the settings wherein.
 
None of them helped me.

Is there any way to reset, disable, bypass, or recover the password?

Comment: -1 password WHERE .  There are BIOS passwords. Windows passwords.  If a BIOS password you might be able to open it and take the battery in and out. Try looking up that model of laptop and BIOS password and see what people have said.  If it is a BIOS password that is the issue

Comment: @barlop, suppose for the sake of argument ALX lost the BIOS password.  "When a User Password is set it must be used to access the BIOS utility." it says on p.20 [here](http://solutions.us.fujitsu.com/www/content/pdf/SupportGuides/Chalice%20BIOS%20FPC58-1571-01.pdf) of a P-Series BIOS manual.  No password, no BIOS access.  But ALX could access it, therefore etc.

Comment: He could recover the data by plugging the HDD into some other PC or booting from LiveCD. If it's just the OS password, he could use the same to bypass the installed OS auth. and get back his access. If it's BIOS, he should dismantle the laptop and take out the CMOS battery to reset BIOS to defaults. But yeah, question lacks details.

Comment: @barlop: instead of immediately down-voting (either only virtually or in reality too), at first please ask in a kind way and have a bit of patience waiting for the answer. You may read more in the [help center](http://superuser.com/help/be-nice)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try a rescue bootcd - here's [a list of some](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_live_CDs#Rescue_and_repair_live_CDs).

Comment: -1 you've neglected to take into account that it might be a BIOS or UEFI password and point out that a boot cd won't help him in that scenario.

Comment: @barlop: The OP was able to _view_ their BIOS settings, suggesting that no BIOS password was set.  That's how it works on at least one P-series BIOS, see p.20 [here](http://solutions.us.fujitsu.com/www/content/pdf/SupportGuides/Chalice%20BIOS%20FPC58-1571-01.pdf).    It's unlikely UEFI would be present on a 13-year old P-series Lifebook.

Comment: ok a boot CD it is then but it's worth pointing out that he's wrong to suggest that no setting in the BIOS helps him, it's worth correcting him on that, and he would probably need to know what options to choose in a rescue boot cd.  Anyhow i've removed the downvote  and made it an upvote, 'cos you make a good point, and your answer would work for a sufficiently skilled user (though even there, screenshots would be interesting and useful and speed things up for them).